# send command from bash script to telegram-cli

Tags: bash, command-line-interface, telegram

I want to add several phone number in a text file to my telegram account using telegram-cli (telegram command line interface). So bash script should read every line in the text file and add_contact it to telegram-cli. How can I send command to telegram-cli from bash script?

Comment: Try pipe, it is the easiest solution.

Comment: How does your file with the contacts look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add contacts over `telegram-cli`, you need to do the following:

1. Move to the directory where telegram-cli is:
2. Open *telegram-cli* with your key
3. Load your contact list with `-W`
4. Add the new contacts

To achieve that:

```
cd /path/to/tg && bin/telegram-cli -W server.pub -e "add_contact <phone-number> <first-name> <last-name>"
```

or

```
cd /path/to/tg && (sleep 1; echo "contact_list"; sleep 1; echo "add_contact <phone-number> <first-name> <last-name>") | bin/telegram-cli -W -k server.pub
```